# Click on page1 and refresh on page 2

Tags: php

I am stuck with a problem. I am not finding further way. Please help me out with the logic.

I have page1.php besing used by user1 and have page2.php used by user2.

Now when the user1 clicks on a button in the page. The page2.php which is being viewed by user 2 must be refreshed.  How can I do that.

Your help is most appreciated.

Thanks!
Abhilash

Comment: can you consider using web sockets for this?

Comment: I think I got the answer!!! I am going with web sockets/message brokers... Thanks  Sanjeev!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot do it in php. Once the page is loaded, PHP dies and is out of control.
You have a few options:
    Use javascript
    Use the refresh meta tag 
I think that the refresh meta tag is the most easy and convenient.**

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using `php` `ajax` and `javascript \ jquery`

just save the click button flag in database, and by using `php` `ajax` continuesly check wether the button click flag is on or off,

if it is on than you can refresh the page by using `javascript.window` function